# npm install not working and showing error

Tags: react-native, npm, installation

At many times I face `npm install` error like this:
Help would be appreciated, Thanks....

```
    npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall spawn git
npm ERR! path git
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! enoent Error while executing:
npm ERR! enoent undefined ls-remote -h -t https://github.com/naver/hammer.js.git
npm ERR! enoent
npm ERR! enoent
npm ERR! enoent spawn git ENOENT
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Rafay\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-03-21T13_50_14_353Z-debug.log
```

Comment: First check if Git installed in your machine correctly. Type git -v in cmd

Comment: E:\bismillah>npm git --version
6.14.3

Comment: git is aready installed

Comment: remove hammer.js from your package.json and run npm install. After that, go to hammer.js github page and follow the instructions and install it again.

Comment: install standalone  git if you are using windows @rafay mustafa     https://git-scm.com/download/win